# How to find out that what urls in sitemap not indexed?

Tags: sitemap

I use google webmaster tools for manage indexed urls. In google webmaster tools we can see the number of *Submitted* urls and *Indexed* such as below image :

[image]

Now How can I find out not indexed urls?